# How to call asterisk function in perl AGI script?

Tags: perl, asterisk, agi

Is there any possibility to call the asterisk function in perl AGI script like CHANNEL function.

extension.conf

```
exten => _X.,1,NoOp(${CHANNEL(dahdi_channel)})
```

above NoOp will print the current call channel no. Same I need in perl AGI script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use perl  [Asterisk::AGI](http://search.cpan.org/~jamesgol/asterisk-perl-1.03/lib/Asterisk/AGI.pm) or fastagi version, you can use

```
$AGI->get_full_variable('${CHANNEL(dahdi_channel)}');
```